# Trouble returning an arrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

For some reason it is saying that my function is not returning anything. but I am writing:

```
return (outputList);
```

...In order to return the arrayList. I'm getting ***missing return statement.***

*Here is the rest of my code*:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> duplicatesRemoval(int [] inputList){
        ArrayList<Integer> outputList = new ArrayList<>();
        int length = inputList.length;
        int i = 0;
        while(i < length){
            int nextElement = inputList[i];
            int lengthOut = outputList.size();
            int j=0;
            boolean found = false;
            while (j <= lengthOut && found){
                int outputElement = outputList.get(j);
                if( nextElement == outputElement){
                    found = true;
                }
                j++;
            }
            if(!found){
                outputList.add(nextElement);
                i++;
        }
    return(outputList);      
}
}
```

Comment: In case `i >= length` from the beginning your method wont return, hence your compiler tells you that it is missing a return statment.

Comment: Note that if you formatted your code more clearly, the problem would be more obvious. Most IDEs have shortcuts to autoformat the code - I strongly urge you to use this feature.

Comment: Yeah thank you, its been a long time since I've done java @JonSkeet

Comment: There's nothing very Java-specific about my comment. Making sure your code is properly formatted for maximum readability is a common concern across all languages, IMO.

Comment: I agree, was just a general statement not a specific reply to your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your return statement is inside the while loop, so it might never be reached (if `inputList` is an empty array).

Comment: Thank you, I realised my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You should return your ArrayList **after** you did work in your while loop

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the answer to your question, but you can use HashMap to avoid duplicates:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> duplicatesRemoval(int [] inputList){ 
  HashMap<Integer, Integer> mArray = new HashMap<>();
  int i = 0;
  while (i < inputList.length){
    mArray.put(inputList(i), inputList(i))
    i++;
  }
  return new ArrayList<Integer>(mArray.values())
}
```